# MongoDB MapReduce memory issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mapreduce, cron

I have an issue with mongoDb mapReduce. I'm doing aggregation of a collection that contain millions of mongoDB documents and output of that aggregated documents are storing in other collection. I'm using cron job to aggregate all documents that run every hour and it works fine. Approximately cron job takes 10 minutes to aggregate all documents. But while aggregation is running using mapReduce and at same time other API call gets timeout because mapReduce talking place in whole memory and API call does not get memory to read / write data from other mongoDB collections.

So, I would like to know from you guys, Is there any way to set uses memory limit for mongoDB mapReduce? So other API call can read / write documents and response within timeout period.

I'm running on Mongolab "M1" cluster with 1.7 GB RAM and 40 GB SSD block storage.

I would like to invite everyone to help me and figure out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run this on a replica set,a sharded cluster or a single instance?

Comment: Hey Markus, Yes I'm running on replica set, a sharded cluster.